# What's the minimum amount of code needed to have a field show up in Manage Fields?

Tags: 7, entities

I tried copying the functions from the field module in [example modules](http://drupal.org/project/examples) to get a field to show up in Manage Fields without necessarily any functionality

Looking at the answer to this question, only field_create_field() and hook_field_info() should do the trick but I never got that working with the following code:

```
function entityreference_add_new_field_info() {
  return array(
       'entityreference_add_link' => array(
          'label' => t('Entityreference link'),
          'description' => t('Entityreference link'),
          'default_widget' => 'entityreference_link_widget',
          'default_formatter' => 'entityreference_link_formatter',
      ),
    );  
  field_create_field('entityreference_add_link');
}
```

Putting `field_create_field()` outside of `hook_field_info()` returns 'call to undefined function' error.

**Update:** Here's one thing I've tried without success:

```
function entityreference_add_new_field_info() {
  return array(
       'entityreference_add_link' => array(
          'label' => t('Entityreference link'),
          'description' => t('Entityreference link'),
          'default_widget' => 'entityreference_link_widget',
          'default_formatter' => 'entityreference_link_formatter',
      ),
    ); 
    field_create_field('entityreference_add_link');


$instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'entityrefernce_add_link',
    'entity_type' => 'node', 
    'label' => 'The Link', 
    'bundle' => 'node', 
  );

field_create_instance($instance);

}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already created the definition of the field, but you also need to create an actual instance of that field to use it.

```
$instance = array(
    'field_name' => $your_field_name,
    'entity_type' => 'node', 
    'label' => $your_field_label, 
    'bundle' => 'node', 
  );

field_create_instance($instance);
```

That plus what you have above should be the minimum you need to get a field to appear in your management screen.

See the [field_create_instance()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) docs for more info about available options.

Comment: Ok tried something that didn't work I'll edit my question with the update. I also would like to add that in www.drupal.org/projects/example there is an example of a field module that constructs a field that you can choose in Manage Fields without a field_create_instance module.

Comment: Looks like those createfield and create_instance functions are used in .install files? I noticed that those functions are used when fields are created on the fly when a new bundle is installed. Am I correct that you can't choose those fields in Manage Fields and use them for other bundels where you set a widget and give it a name?